# Histograms in R with ggplot2 (axis ticks,breaks)

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, axis

Hello everyone I have some data with which I need to create a nice histogram.
Firstly I used the `hist()` to create a base one and after researching I found out that it uses the sturges method to count how many bins will be needed. In order to make a more customizable and good-looking histogram, I tried using the `ggplot` package and manually entering the number of bins I need. As you can see in the photos the histograms are not the same cause on the y-axis using hist()it reaches up to 60 freq while with the ggplot it surpasses that.
Additionally, I'm having a hard time getting the ggplot to show proper ticks on the X I can't find any reference on how to mod the tick marks so that they align with the breaks without messing up the graph.
Any ideas and help would be really appreciated.

Photos:
https://prnt.sc/greVRNoGo67T
https://prnt.sc/bMl29-2Fr5BN

Comment: Base function `hist` has a `breaks` argument. And functions `help('nclass.Sturges')` and others. Argument `breaks` can be set to predetermined values or to a function that computes the breakpoints.

Comment: Will that give me ticks for every 300.000 and also align the ticks ? Cause i tried it and i cant get it to work i would like for the x axis to be exactly like the one i get with the hist() function.

Comment: In gglot the ticks are not aligned with the bars but read the help page, the paragraph right before section `Orientation` says this should be possible by experimentation with the arguments values. With base `hist` the default is to align the tick marks with the bars and you can manually compute the break points with `seq(., by = 300000)`.

Comment: Just did that and now what seems strange is that the histogram starts from a value lower than 3.000.000 which no observation is lower than this number let me show you in a photo. Eitherway i really appreciate you taking the time to answer! https://prnt.sc/y1R68CXyPnOe

Comment: I made a mistake, in base `hist` the default is *not* to align the tick marks with the bars, it is to align with *some* of the bars. `hist` calls `?pretty` to have axis labels at multiples of 5 and 10.

Comment: In your `ggplot` code, try `binwidth = 1e5`. This will give you around 35 bins. The plot in the link seems to have too few bins, increase their number and the bars will start nearer min(data).

Comment: Tried it doesnt work...i think il just use the hist() function

Comment: How many rows does your data set have? If it's not too big post `dput(df['Total_Volume'])`, if it is, post `dput(head(df['Total_Volume'], 30))`.

Comment: So up until now the best i can get is the photo ill provide. I have the following issues:
First as you can see on the bottom left my graphs shows that there are values<3.000.0000 while in the data such think doesn't exist. In a addition i want to have the tick marks for every bin, like you know the start of the bin till its end.
https://prnt.sc/i_pSk0cWPaCl   the code im using is 
(> ggplot(df,aes(x=Total_Volume))+geom_histogram(bins=7)+scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(3000000,6500000,by=500000))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is to do some pre-processing and plot a bar plot.
The pre-processing is to bin the data with `cut`. This transforms the continuous variable `Total_Volume` in a categorical variable but since it is done in a pipe the transformation is temporary, the original data remains unchanged.

The breaks are equidistant and the labels are the mid point values rounded.

Note that the very small counts are plotted with bars that are not visible. But they are there.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

brks <- seq(min(x) - 1, max(x) + 1, length.out = 30)
labs <- round(brks[-1] + diff(brks)/2)

data.frame(Total_Volume = x) %>%
  mutate(Total_Volume = cut(x, breaks = brks, labels = labs)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Total_Volume)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data creation code.

```r
set.seed(2022)
n <- 1e6
x <- rchisq(n, df = 1, ncp = 5.5e6)
i <- x > 5.5e6
x[i] <- rnorm(sum(i), mean = 5.5e6, sd = 1e4)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Your last answer was really helpful thank you!